# How to remove a row from result having duplicate item

Tags: sql, postgresql

Suppose I have this query:

```
 select item_display_name 
 from all_requirements 
 where state = 'submitted_pending' and id = 'mNAr9viL4='
```

This displays two results/rows:

```
'id proof'
'id proof'
```

because one of the values in column `document_id` of `all_requirements` is different.

I want the query to only return `id proof` once. How can I do it?

Comment: If your result set include a single column that is repeated you can add `DISTINCT` in the first line, as in `select distinct item_display_name `.

Answer (score 0):

Adding DISTINCT to your Select statement works with 1 column.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ITEM_DISPLAY_NAME 
FROM ALL_REQUIREMENTS 
WHERE
    STATE = 'submitted_pending'
    AND id = 'mNAr9viLD4='
```

If you want to include the document_id column or other columns, then you can use the following code to return 1 record for each unique Item_Display_Name.  The Order By statement sorted in ASC order will give you the record with the lowest document_ID, but you can change it to DESC order to give you the one record with the highest document_ID.

```
SELECT
    R.ITEM_DISPLAY_NAME,
    R.document_id
FROM
(
    SELECT
        ITEM_DISPLAY_NAME,
        document_id,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition BY ITEM_DISPLAY_NAME ORDER BY document_id ASC) AS 'Ranks'
    FROM ALL_REQUIREMENTS
    WHERE
        STATE = 'submitted_pending'
        AND id = 'mNAr9viLD4='
) R
WHERE Ranks = 1
```

Comment: You can also change it to SELECT * to select all of the fields.  The query will still filter out the duplicate rows, and return only 1 row for each unique value in the ITEM_DISPLAY_NAME field.